# Access when GROUP BY in table1 and take the FIRST, how do I update a reference in table2?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named `brand1`, where brands are repeated multiple times (but shouldn't be):

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | FORD      |
|  2 | FIAT      |
|  3 | FIAT      |
|  4 | FIAT IND. |
+----+-----------+
```

So I'm grouping by `name` on `brand1` obtaining `brand2` table. So far so good:

```
SELECT 
    FIRST(b.id) AS id, 
    TRIM(b.name) AS name
FROM brand AS b
GROUP BY TRIM(b.name)
ORDER BY FIRST(b.id)

+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | FORD      |
|  2 | FIAT      | <- the first id found in the grouping
|  4 | FIAT IND. |
+----+-----------+
```

The problem is: my second table `model` has a reference to the `brand1` table (column `brand_id`) so i need to "translate" that reference and get the right `brand_id` found in table `brand2`:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id |  name   | brand_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | Model A |        1 |
|  2 | Model A |        2 | <-- should be 2 as FIAT is repeated in brand1
|  3 | Model B |        3 | <-- should be 2 as FIAT is repeated in brand1
|  4 | Model C |        4 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

What I've tried is not working (Model B gets brand_id 3):

```
SELECT
    FIRST(m.id) AS id,
    FIRST(TRIM(m.name)) AS name,
    FIRST(m.brand_id) AS brand_id
FROM model AS m
GROUP BY TRIM(m.name), m.brand_id
ORDER BY FIRST(m.id)
```

Maybe this is very very easy to accomplish but I've to admin I'm not very good playing with MS Access.

Result should look like:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id |  name   | brand_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 | Model A |        1 |
|  2 | Model A |        2 |
|  3 | Model B |        2 |
|  4 | Model C |        4 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Comment: To avoid complex queries (such as Gordon's subqueries) in long run, I would advise cleaning up your tables now such as: 1) dedup `brand` and 2) update `model` foreign key to use current brand_id and not previous ones (one strategy on the latter is first add a field in `model` for brand name, update FK to corresponding deduped brand_id, then remove name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `FIRST()`, use `MIN()`:

```
SELECT MIN(b.id) AS id, 
       TRIM(b.name) AS name
FROM brand AS b
GROUP BY TRIM(b.name)
ORDER BY MIN(b.id);
```

However, this will give you only three rows.  To get a row for each model, you will need a `JOIN` or correlated subquery:

```
select m.*,
       (select min(b2.id)
        from brand as b2
        where trim(b2.name) = trim(b.name)
       ) as new_id
from model as m inner join
     brand as b
     on m.brand_id = b.id
```

EDIT:

If you actually want to update the data:

```
update model
    set brand_id = (select min(b2.id)
                    from brands as b inner join
                         brands as b2
                         on trim(b.name) = trim(b2.name)
                    where b.id = model.brand_id
                   );
```

Comment: Is safe to compare just the names? where trim(b2.name) = trim(b.name)

Comment: @gremo . . . I don't know what you mean by "is it safe".  That is what you want to do:  compare the names and get the smallest id associated with each name.

Comment: Sorry you are right, if I group by name in the first place then I can compare names to get the min id - thank you it works.